# How to create a Varnish compatible theme in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, varnish

Since Magento 2 now supports Varnish out of the box, is there anything in particular to have in mind while creating themes regarding compatibility with Varnish? 
Is there any mechanism to use for hole punching? 
Is there any official guide to follow?

Comment: does Magento 2 varnish cache supports holes?? hm i need to check it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Themes should not have any issues they need to concern themselves with. The issue is around blocks. If they generate content that should not be cached, so need to report "this content should not be cached". There is also the ability to associate cache tags to allow selective cache purging. But this is not theme related - it is block php code related. A lot of m2 was to take this pain away from developers.